# Python: How to search all file types for a text string

Tags: python, search, python-3.x, win32com

I'm trying to write a program which will be able to search all files (both the file names and their contents) in a user-specified directory for a particular string, and then move these files to a new user-specified directory.

EDIT: Ok, so I've made a few changes to my code. The way it now works is: a list of files is obtained using os.path.walk(). Then, each file in the list is searched for the string specified by the user. First only the file names are checked for the string, and any positive matches are moved to a separate list. Then we start to look inside the files, using the file extension to determine how to open the file via win32com.client. Finally, any files still in the original list are assumed to be plain text files, and are opened and searched accordingly.

However, for whatever reason only the plain text files are being moved by the program. If anyone can figure out why this is, it would be a huge help. :)

```
################
#Import required modules
import fileinput
from shutil import move
from os.path import abspath, join, splitext, split
from os import mkdir, walk, remove
import win32com.client

################
#Create lists to hold file names
file_list = list()
file_move_list = list()

#Define file extensions which need to be converted
excel_set = [".xls", ".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xlsb"]
msword_set = [".doc", ".docx"]

################
#Define functions
def getFileList( searchdirectory ):
    #Get a list of all items in the directory to search
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk( searchdirectory ):
        for path in [ abspath( join( dirpath, filename ) ) for filename in filenames ]:
            file_list.append( path )

def searchFiles( readfilelist, movefilelist, searchstring ):
    #Get plain text from each file and search for searchstring
    for filename in readfilelist:
        ext = splitext( filename )[1]
        #Check filenames
        if searchstring in filename:
            movefilelist.append( filename )
            readfilelist.remove( filename )
        #Check if file is a pdf
        elif ext == ".pdf":
            content = getPDFContent( filename )
            if searchstring in content:
                movefilelist.append( filename )
        #Check if file is a word document
        elif ext in msword_set:
            app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application') 
            doc = app.Documents.Open( filename ) 
            if searchstring in doc.Content.Text:
                movefilelist.append( filename )
            app.Quit()
        #Check if file is an excel workbook/spreadsheet
        elif ext in excel_set:
            app = win32com.client.Dispatch( 'Excel.Application' )
            fileDir, fileName = split( filename )
            nameOnly = splitext( fileName )
            newName = nameOnly[0] + ".csv"
            outCSV = join( fileDir, newName )
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Open( filename )
            workbook.SaveAs(outCSV, FileFormat=24) # 24 is csv format
            workbook.Close(False)
            for line in open( outCSV, mode='r' ):
                if searchstring in line:
                    movefilelist.append( filename )
            app.Quit()
            remove( outCSV )
        #Assume all other files are plain text
        else:
            for line in open( filename, mode='r' ):
                if searchstring in line:
                    movefilelist.append( filename )
        readfilelist.remove( filename )

def moveFiles( movelist, destinationdirectory ):
    mkdir( destinationdirectory )
    for path in movelist:
        #Move the files to the destination folder
        move( path, destinationdirectory )
    print( 'Done' )

def getPDFContent( filename ):
    content = ""
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader( file( filename, "rb" ) )
    # Extract text from each page and add to content
    for i in range( 0, pdf.getNumPages() ):
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + " \n"
    return content

################
#Run as main
if __name__=='__main__':
    search_directory = input( 'Enter the path of the directory you wish to search through: ' )
    search_string = input( 'Enter the search term: ' )
    destination_directory = input( 'Enter the name of the new directory which will contain the moved files: ' )
    getFileList( search_directory )
    searchFiles( file_list, file_move_list, search_string )
    moveFiles( file_move_list, destination_directory )
```

Any help I can get on this is much appreciated. (FYI, I'm using Python 3.2.1)

Comment: Will this be run on Windows only? If so, maybe findstr command could be used using os.system.

Comment: In contrast to serk's comment: On Unix you can do so with `grep -R` and  `xargs`

Comment: And the particular problem is?

Comment: @serk and phant0m: For now I'm only concerned with getting it to work on Windows, portability isn't a huge issue at the moment.
@Blackmoon: The problem is that I'm currently unable to search inside .pdf, .jpg, .xls, and pretty much all other "binary" filetypes for a string of plain text.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is needing this code, I got it working correctly. Make sure you install `PyPDF2` and `win32com.client`

```
################
#Import required modules
import fileinput
from shutil import move
from os.path import abspath, join, splitext, split
from os import mkdir, walk, remove
import win32com.client
import PyPDF2 as pyPdf

################
#Create lists to hold file names
file_list = list()
file_move_list = list()

#Define file extensions which need to be converted
excel_set = [".xls", ".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xlsb"]
msword_set = [".doc", ".docx"]

################
#Define functions
def getFileList( searchdirectory ):
    #Get a list of all items in the directory to search
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk( searchdirectory ):
        for path in [ abspath( join( dirpath, filename ) ) for filename in filenames ]:
            file_list.append( path )

def searchFiles( readfilelist, movefilelist, searchstring ):
    #Get plain text from each file and search for searchstring
    for filename in readfilelist:
        ext = splitext( filename )[1]
        #Check filenames
        if searchstring in filename:
            movefilelist.append( filename )
            readfilelist.remove( filename )
        #Check if file is a pdf
        elif ext == ".pdf":
            content = getPDFContent( filename )
            if searchstring in content:
                movefilelist.append( filename )
        #Check if file is a word document
        elif ext in msword_set:
            app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application') 
            doc = app.Documents.Open( filename ) 
            if searchstring in doc.Content.Text:
                movefilelist.append( filename )
            app.Quit()
        #Check if file is an excel workbook/spreadsheet
        elif ext in excel_set:
            app = win32com.client.Dispatch( 'Excel.Application' )
            fileDir, fileName = split( filename )
            nameOnly = splitext( fileName )
            newName = nameOnly[0] + ".csv"
            outCSV = join( fileDir, newName )
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Open( filename )
            workbook.SaveAs(outCSV, FileFormat=24) # 24 is csv format
            workbook.Close(False)
            for line in open( outCSV, mode='r' ):
                if searchstring in line:
                    movefilelist.append( filename )
            app.Quit()
            remove( outCSV )
        #Assume all other files are plain text
        elif ext == ".txt":
            txtFile = open(filename, mode='r')
            for line in txtFile:
                if searchstring in line:
                    movefilelist.append( filename )
            txtFile.close()
        else:
            print(filename + " is not reconized")
        #readfilelist.remove( filename )

def moveFiles( movelist, destinationdirectory ):
    mkdir( destinationdirectory )
    for path in movelist:
        #Move the files to the destination folder
        move( path, destinationdirectory )
    print( 'Done' )

def getPDFContent( filename ):
    content = ""
    fd = file(filename, 'rb')
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader( fd )
    # Extract text from each page and add to content
    for i in range( 0, pdf.getNumPages() ):
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + " \n"
    fd.close()
    return content

################
#Run as main
if __name__=='__main__':
    search_directory = input( 'Enter the path of the directory you wish to search through, in this format "C:\Users\admin\folder" : ' )
    search_string = input( 'Enter the search term in quotes: ' )
    destination_directory = input( 'Enter the name of the new directory which will contain the moved files, in this format"C:\Users\admin\folder" : ' )

    getFileList( search_directory )
    searchFiles( file_list, file_move_list, search_string )
    moveFiles( file_move_list, destination_directory )
```

Comment: FYI This is using Python2.7

Answer (score 0):

For windows consider this:

```
os.system('findstr /C:"text to search for" *.*')
```

This pretty much does everything you want.

Comment: Oddly enough, I don't get any kind of output from findstr when I use it in the command prompt - it just hangs until I enter an EOF char.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [grin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grin/1.2.1) library ([source](https://svn.enthought.com/svn/sandbox/grin/trunk/grin.py)). It's usable both as a console script and a library you can build on. There is support for detecting binary files.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert pdf, xls, etc. first as they are in raster or vector formats, so there is no text to search for.  There are tools, like pdtotext, that will convert them for you and you can then search the output.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid doing this as it seems less efficient in terms of overhead, but I guess there's no getting around it :P I've made some changes in my code to reflect needing to convert certain files, and to outright open others using win32com to see their contents.